# Centering div horizontally and vertically without distorting content

Tags: css, html, position, center

I am trying to center the div with id="center" both vertically and horizontally within the body tag without distorting the placement of the content: M, cicle div and Coming soon... text. Can't really get it to work even though it should be a simple thing..

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="center">
        <div class="circle"><div>M</div></div>
        <h2>Coming soon...</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: futura;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

h2 {
    color: #f6c003;
    font-family: serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.circle {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f6c003;
}

.circle div {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    padding-top:25px;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuV2z/1/)

Comment: Asking how to center an element that takes the whole width does not make sense …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some absolute positioning to get it done

```
#center {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin: -33px 0 0 -43px;
}
```

The key being that you have negative margins of half the width and half the height to properly position th element ( fixed size only )

Also make sure your body is set to `position: relative;` in order for the absolute positioning to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
}

h2 {
color: #f6c003;
font-family: serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 0.9em;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.circle {
text-align: center;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
-moz-border-radius: 50%; 
-webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
border-radius: 50%;
background: #f6c003;
}

.circle div {
float:left;
width:50px;
padding-top:25px;
line-height:1em;
margin-top:-0.5em;
text-align:center;
color:black;
font-style: bold;
font-weight: 700;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 2.5em;
}
#center
{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="center">
<div class="circle"><div>M</div></div>
<h2>Coming soon...</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate tables, tables do a good job of vertically aligning. Maybe there's a better way?

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="center">
                    <div class="circle"><div>M</div></div>
                    <h2>Coming soon...</h2>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Style:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.center {
    margin: auto;
}
```